# Как вывести на экран лист например с айдишками танков, чтоб они располагались сверху вниз по очереди? В pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
  text = font.render('tank id: {}. health: {}. score: {}'.format(tank_id, tank_health, tank_score), 
                                                                 True, (0, 0, 0))
                textRect = text.get_rect()
                textRect.center = (600, 15)
                screen.blit(text, textRect)
```

Если я так пишу то все айдишки пишутся на одном месте и  закрывают друг-друга.

Answer (score 0):

Не использовал pygame, но как я понял, вы в цикле проходите по всей коллекции и по очереди выводите элементы. Попробуйте в цикле добавлять к переменной textRect.center смещение. Например:

```
for i in range(len(tanks)):
  # ...
  offset_y = 15 + i * 10
  textRect.center = (600, 15 + offset_y)
  screen.blit(text, textRect)
```

, где 10 - необходимое расстояние между строчками.